# VIM key map doesn't work as expected

Tags: vim

I've got following key map:

```
nmap <F9> :s/^/\/\*! /<cr>:s/$/ !\*\//<cr>j
```

It is intended to comment line in C style. When I hit `<F9>` it works fine. But when I try preceed it with number(to comment specified amount of lines) it misses closing bracket `*/` on every line except the last one. It looks like:

```
/*! foo1;
/*! foo2;
/*! foo3; !*/
```

I've got similar key map to uncomment:

```
nmap  <F10>   :s/^\/\*! //e<cr>:s/ !\*\/$//e<cr>j
```

and situation is analogous(doesn't remove closing bracket).

EDIT:

[Ha! I found solution.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29#Supplying_a_count_to_a_map)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `vim` keymaps usually does not support lineranges. But there are some workarounds:

1. set up a visual selection (of lines) and change your mapping to: `nmap <F9> :'<,'>s/^/\/\*! /<cr>:'<,'>s/$/ !\*\//<cr>j` (and note that you can issue more ex commands on one line so you can "shorten" it to `nmap <F9> :'<,'>s/^/\/\*! /|'<,'>s/$/ !\*\//<cr>j`
2. but I would recommend using a plugin for this: [NERD commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) is really capable...

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...tricky. This is something to do with the first substitute command being converted to the range `:.,.+n`, but the second one only acting on the final line. I'm not quite sure why that's happening, but converting to a single substitution solves the problem. So, collapsing into one call and then tidying up a little, this works:

`nnoremap <F9> :s!.*!/* & */!<CR>j`

(Note the use of `!` instead of `/` as a pattern separator. You can use `:s` with (almost) any character. `/` is just the default. If your pattern uses a lot of `/`s, it's sensible to use something else and save yourself some escapes.)